# remove particular key=>value from array php

Tags: php, arrays, unset

i have a array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [to_id] => 3
            [email] => ngkarthick.kumar@gmail.com
            [user_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [to_id] => 2
            [email] => karthickkumarganesh@gmail.com
            [user_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [to_id] => 5
            [email] => phpkarthick@outlook.com
            [user_id] => 5
        )

)
```

and i would like to get array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => ngkarthick.kumar@gmail.com
            [user_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => karthickkumarganesh@gmail.com
            [user_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [email] => phpkarthick@outlook.com
            [user_id] => 5
        )

)
```

i got this working by looping with foreach , but i would like to do it single array function ,is it possible ,please help

Comment: you would most likely be able to achieve this with an array_map or array_walk being used in conjunction with a closure

Comment: I would just copy the old array into a new array ommiting that key in the copy process

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = array_map(
    function (array $ar) { return array_diff_key($ar, array_flip(array('to_id'))); },
    $array
);
```

There's no one single function which does this. You have to write a bit of code. You will also always have to loop through the array. You can only dress that loop up in different ways and dress the action of unsetting the key up in different ways. I wouldn't necessarily think anything is anymore efficient or clearer than a straight forward loop. But, well, go with the above if you're looking for something more fancy.

Comment: this will do the work , but i need some things like unset($array['to_id']); will loop through and remove in whole array

Comment: Nothing like that exists. You could write a function like `unset_key($array, 'to_id')` which would do it. But it doesn't exist by default.

Comment: thanks ,how to inform the php community to create some predefined function to do like so in next release

Comment: http://bugs.php.net - But... I don't think they're going to. PHP already has enough functions as is, nobody needs the hyper specific function in the core when it's trivially implemented in user land code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is the array name in which your data is stored.
$my_array = array($array_data);

// now lets get one level inside the array 
foreach($my_array as $key => $value ){

// ok now unset un-wanted index from the array into a temporary array
unset($value['to_id']);

// overwrite our temporary array to original array keeping the keys same as before.
$my_array[$key] = $value;
//Thats it your Problem Solved :)
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: my questions is not to do with foreach

Comment: This may not be the best method however it does work. Try to avoid irrelevant details such as your "Bonus" section.